# jQuery load the same page after PHP submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently struggling because I want to load the same page submited by PHP. To make this more clear, it's a comment section, where after people submit their message I would like to retrieve the same information PLUS the new one.

I'm having problems because I'm not doing this by AJAX.

So, the index.php has the following:

```
/* Before HTML tag */
if(Cookie::Exists('comment')){
    $data = unserialize(stripslashes(Cookie::Get('comment')));
    if($data['status'] == 1){
        $page = "<script type='text/javascript'>set_product_id('" . $data['id'] . "')</script>";
    }
    Cookie::Delete('comment', time() - 3600);
}

/* Further ahead.. (inside body) */
<form method="POST" action="insert_info.php" data-ajax="false">
    <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id"/>
    <input type="text" id="name_" name="name_" required="required"/>
    <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" required="required"/>
</form>

/* After body */
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page-comments", function() {
    $(function(){
        get_comments(objs.product_id);
    });
});

var objs = {
    product_id : ''
}

function set_product_id(id){
    objs.product_id = id;
    $.mobile.changePage('#page-comments', {role: 'dialog'}); 
}
</script>

/* After the HTML tag */
<?php echo $page; ?>
```

I do receive the correct ID, etc, also it works perfectly before submiting the comment. The page loads the content without any problem, etc.

insert_info.php

```
new_comment($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$arr = array("status" => 1, "id" => $_POST['product_id']);
Cookie::set('comment', serialize($arr), time()+60);

header("Location: ../index.php");
exit();
```

When I perform this operation, I do receive the following erro on google chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'trigger' of undefined
```

Poiting to the line:

```
function set_product_id(id){
    objs.product_id = id;
    $.mobile.changePage('#page-comments', {role: 'dialog'}); 
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

**EDIT:** changing the set_product_id() function, to this:

```
$('#page-main').on('pagecreate', function(event) {
    $.mobile.changePage('#page-comments', {role: 'dialog'}); 
});
```

The page of comments appears and disappears again. But if I remove the "dialog", the page stays and works correctly. But I need that to be on dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$.mobile.changePage()` needs to contain a url..

So this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page-comments', {role: 'dialog'});
```

Should be something like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('../index.php', {role: 'dialog'});
```

Comment: I think you missed something.. I want to open the page of comments which is #page-comments not the index.php again..because that I already did on PHP side, when redirecting. EDIT: btw, see my edited post.

Comment: I just put '`index.php`' in there to show that this need to be a '`url`', so in that case, what is the `URL` of #page-comments?  is it `index.php#page-comments`?  or `someurl.html#page-comments`.  You get what I'm saying?  It need to be a `url`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Doesn't work. I got the same error. If I put like my edited post your solution, the page appears and disappears and I got no error.

Comment: maybe your missing what the $.mobile.changePage() function actually does.. ?  putting {role: 'dialog') does not make the page show up in a dialog.  It just sets the `data-role` attribute of the element to `"dialog"`. See here - http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/ . I'm not sure if I totally understand correctly, but maybe you need to be looking at implementing a uidialog. - here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/